# Mybatis annotation how to return hashmap key item if value is null

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-generator

springboot mybatis example:

```
@Select({"select id,xx from table where id=#{id}"})
Map<String,Object> queryById(@Param("id") Long id);
```

if table xx is null, the returned map does not contains xx key.

I search for a long time, 
mapper.xml could configure `<setting name="callSettersOnNulls" value="true"/>`
 could solve my problem, but I do not use xml configuration mode, how to config param callSettersOnNulls using mybatis annotation??

Answer (score 0):

i say no, **callSettersOnNulls** now only support the global configuration, it can't support on specific method

see the source code of mybatis:

```
org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler
applyPropertyMappings() or applyAutomaticMappings()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem right now. I don't solve it yet

Answering the question

> how to config param callSettersOnNulls using mybatis annotation

, the configuration would be something like this.

```
import org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.ConfigurationCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MyBatisConfiguration {

    @Bean
    ConfigurationCustomizer mybatisConfigurationCustomizer() {
        return new ConfigurationCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public void customize(org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration configuration) {
                configuration.setCallSettersOnNulls(true);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer or not?  The first sentence says is not, but the second sentence says it is.  Please edit the answer to clarify.

Comment: @RichG My answer is for 'how to config param callSettersOnNulls using mybatis annotation'